# why I cannot read a big data file in java?

Tags: java, maven

My program compile wihout any error. But when executing big file, i got the following exception:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project rdf4j-getting-started: 
    An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: The parser has encountered
 more than "100,000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application. -> [Help 1]
```

I was using the following command:

```
mvn -Djdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit=0 -DentityExpansionLimit=0  exec:java
```

my pom with all the dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>rdf4j-getting-started</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>HelloRDF4J</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>rdf4j-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.0M2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>utf8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>ConvertOntology</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Im using the following java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_192"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_192-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.192-b12, mixed mode)
```

any help please

Comment: Please let us see you pom.xml and your Java code.

Comment: @PowerStat check please the code. Noting that for small file it works vey well

Comment: I think your pom would be more interesting, because it uses exec-maven-plugin - which reported the error.

Comment: @PowerStat  Check please

Comment: One quick google search turned up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328402/how-do-i-set-entity-expansion-limit-in-java).

Comment: @cmoetzing the majority of answers suggest the use of the same parameter that i was used

Comment: @moudi If you set it to zero and it still uses 100k something did not work.

Comment: 0 means no limits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set Entity Expansion Limit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328402/how-do-i-set-entity-expansion-limit-in-java)

Comment: @moudi I do not find any reference in the documentation that 0 is a valid value. Did you try to set it to 1M?

Comment: @cmoetzing https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/limits.html

Comment: I stopped reading too early. Right at the end it says it does NOT spawn a new JVM. But it also says you should pass options with `MAVEN_OPTS`. My bad. Can you try this?

Comment: Which parameters?

Comment: @cmoetzing which parameters you mean?

Comment: @moudi As described [here](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) I would expect your command to look like this `MAVEN_OPTS="-Djdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit=0 -DentityExpansionLimit=0" mvn exec:java` (not really sure why they explicitly mention this, I thought it to be equivilant to your approach) or you need to use the [systemProperties plugin parameter](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#systemProperties).

Comment: @cmoetzing similar exception is generated :(

Comment: Please verify that your solution does work without maven. Start your application with  `java -Djdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit=123 -DentityExpansionLimit=123  -jar your.jar`. Do not use 0. Your exception must contain your set limit. Only then it makes sense to search where the problem is with maven. We do not have your program nor your data file so we can not reproduce your error.

Comment: @cmoetzing something strange i still get the same error. you can try http://www.l3s.de/~minack/rdf2rdf/ and convert the big file swetoDBLP in http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2009/instances/  to reproduce the same exception

Answer (score 1):

My command is right. I solved this problem by adding to pom file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
```